# Unable to create notification icon on Android Studio using custom image

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to create notification icon using custom png image on Android studio. In Configure Image Asset Screen, when I select my custom image, all it is showing 5 black boxes with white circles in it. Can any one please let me know why it is not selecting custom image.

Below is screenshot of Android Studio

[image]

Below is custom image with which I am trying to create notification icon

[image]

Can any one please let me know why it is not selecting custom image.

Comment: Have the same issue. Do you know solution?

Comment: The icon should contain one color (second color should not be present. It should be transparent). My Icon contains red and white both. I asked design team to create an image which has only one color and remaining area as transparent. I created notification icons using that image given by design team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon should contain one color (second color should not be present. It should be transparent). My Icon contains red and white both. That is the reason Android studio is not able to identify the image and displaying the whole image as white circle. I asked design team to create an image which has only one color and remaining area as transparent. I created notification icons using that image given by design team.